# How to skip an id that is mapped to multiple values based upon one of those value from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I understand it may sound confusing so let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. I have following data.

```
trxn_id      event_value
1567           4
1567           1
1567          23
2568           1
2568           4
2568           5
```

Now, I need to select all those transaction which don't have the event_value `23`.

If I do `select trxn_id from table where event_value<>23` then apparently I'll get the trxn id since other event_value's appear in it too.

what I did to solve this is select distinct trxn_id and loop through them and insert only the ones which don't have event_value 23. Like below.

```
FOR v_intrim_loop1 IN (select distinct t.trxn_id from table t)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
    if(not exists(select 1 from table where event_id=23 and trxn_id=v_intrim_loop1.trxn_id)) THEN
        insert into temp_table(trxn_id) values (v_intrim_loop1.trxn_id);
    END IF;
    END;
 END LOOP;
```

I believe there's a simple and more efficient way to do this. Please let me know how. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT trxn_id FROM mytable GROUP BY trnx_id HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN event_value = 23 THEN 1 END) = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trxn_id
from table1
group by trxn_id
having count(case event_value when 23 then 1 end) = 0
```

The idea is to use `group by` to create chunks of rows with the same `trxn_id`.

We then use `having` to filter out all chunks that have more than 0 rows with `event_value = 23`. `1` is just a dummy non-null value here; if `event_value` is not 23, the `case` expression returns `null`, which is skipped by `count`.

Comment: So does "having" apply to the whole group? Whichever group has event_value=23 will be skipped, right?

Comment: @AnandTyagi Yes, see also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP: "*If a table has been grouped using `GROUP BY`, but only certain groups are of interest, the `HAVING` clause can be used, much like a `WHERE` clause, to eliminate groups from the result.*"

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood, you want to skip `trxn_id` -> `1567` since it appears in `event_value` -> `23`.

If I have understood right, this query will help you.

```
SELECT 
    distinct trxn_id 
FROM 
    tablename
WHERE 
    trxn_id NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT trxn_id from tablename where event_value=23
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT trxn_id , event_value
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE trxn_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT trxn_id
                         WHERE event_value = 23
                      )
```